# Error print() en Python

Tags: print

Estoy empezando a formarme en Python con cursos de internet. Y ya tengo mi primer error que no logro soluciona. Escribo algo tan sencillo como lo siguiente:

```
a = 5
b = 4
c = a + b 

print(c)
```

Y el error que me aparece es el siguiente:

> > > print(c)
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > NameError: name 'c' is not defined

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: *... line 1, in NameError...* Me extraña que mencione la línea 1 ¿Hay algo más antes del fragmento de código que pones? ¿Has guardado los cambios del archivo?, ¿qué IDE estás usando?